# Moving title to header

Tags: header-footer, titles

I am trying to write a new class file for forms. I wish to redefine title so that it occurs inside `\rhead{}` (using the `fancyhdr` class). This is not a query about `\markboth` or anything like that.

How would one go about redefining it?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am not sure a MWE is relevant at this stage. I do not have any code that can possibly do this. I tried to redefine `\title` using `    \makeatletter
    \def\@maketitle{
    { \rhead{\huge \scshape \bfseries \@title}}
     }
     \makeatother` I get no output upon compilation.

Comment: Is it really necessary to start with a class file. Changing from the usual classes is perhaps also a good starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is. I have a huge number of forms to change, and we need consistency of appearance. So, how does one redefine `\maketitle` so that it appears in say, `\rhead{}` for `fancyhdr` class?? A complicating fact I found was that the standard `\maketitle` redefines the page style to plain (so you have to use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle`). Please help.

Comment: It is always possible to bypass the `\maketitle` command

Comment: Agree with @ChristianHupfer: why use `\maketitle` at all? This is why an MWE is so important: we have no idea what you are really trying to do. That means this is almost certainly an XY problem, which means there is not much point in trying to answer right now. (Of course, one can always guess. But then the question is: why do you require potential helpers to guess?)

Answer (score 2):

As the question is pretty cloudy, this is a suggestion based on plain `article`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{%
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
}{}{}{}
\apptocmd{\title}{\rhead{#1}}{}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\title{this is just a test}
\author{not me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: texsxTitleToHead]